# Search Value from range of an array

Tags: php, arrays, range

I am trying to find value from different ranges.

e.g.
I have one value is 5 and now i have different ranges like [0,100], [101-500] and [501-1000], so how can I conclude that my value 5 is in range of [0,100] using php.

I have tried in_array but it is considering only one range, like below:

```
$arr = array("5", "25", "100", "200", "500");
foreach($arr as $val){
$i = $val; // Dynamic value   
if (in_array($i, range(0,10))) {
echo 'Your number is in between of range array';
}
}
```

Here i can take only one range, I need to check different ranges there. how can I do that ? range value[0,100],[101,500] and [501,1000] are fixed.

Comment: Yes, `in_array()` only takes a single range .. so you have to write an inner loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may do the action you want.

```
$range[1] = array (0,101,501);
$range[2] = array (100,500,1000);
$testNumber=7;
$count = count($range);
for ($i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++) 
{
    if ($testNumber>=$range[1][$i])
    {
        if  ($testNumber<=$range[2][$i])
        {
            echo $testNumber." is in range of [".$range[1][$i].' , '.$range[2][$i]."]";
            break;
        }
    }
    else if($testNumber<$range[1][$i])
    {
       echo "not found";break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$rangeList = array("0-100","101-500","501-1000");

$testNo = 5;

foreach($rangeList as $range){
    list($start,$end) = explode("-",$range);
    if( $testNo >= $start && $testNo <= $end )
        die("Your number $testNo is in between of range [ $range ]");   
}
//out of range
die("Your number $testNo is out of range");
```

Is what you need?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you already have part of the code written. All you need are a few more else if statements to check the other ranges you're looking for. As a bonus, this also prints out the number that fell into the three ranges you're looking at.

```
$arr = array("5", "25", "100", "200", "500");

foreach($arr as $val) {
    $i = $val; // Dynamic value   
    if (in_array($i, range(0,100))) {
        echo "Your number {$i} is in between of range array (0-100)\n";
    }
    else if (in_array($i, range(101,500))) {
        echo "Your number {$i} is in between of range array (101-500)\n";
    }
    else if (in_array($i, range(501,1000))) {
        echo "Your number {$i} is in between of range array (501-1000)\n";
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
Your number 5 is in between of range array (0-100)
Your number 25 is in between of range array (0-100)
Your number 100 is in between of range array (0-100)
Your number 200 is in between of range array (101-500)
Your number 500 is in between of range array (101-500)
```

Comment: Thanks very much :) It helps me a lot. I set rest of other conditions as per your code. Thanks again :)